# Rust SQLite INSERT Prepared Statement

Tags: sqlite, rust, prepared-statement

I am not able to use `INSERT` query with `bind` while using the [SQLite crate](https://docs.rs/sqlite/0.26.0/sqlite/).

Here is my code

```
let connection = &connect_db();
    
let mut statement = connection.prepare("INSERT INTO History(field_1,field_2,field_3) VALUES(?,?,?)").unwrap();
statement.bind(1,45).unwrap();
statement.bind(2,42).unwrap();
statement.bind(3,65).unwrap();
statement.execute();
```

Comment: What's the error? Can you create a [mre]?

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for `statement.next()?`

via https://docs.rs/sqlite/0.24.0/sqlite/struct.Statement.html